# how find program has device driver

Tags: api, device-driver

how can i find whether a program has device driver or not (or know program run in ring0 or ring3)

i need function(api) for this in c# or c/c++
like regmon it has device driver

thank

Comment: I believe ring0 programs always run as the user `SYSTEM`

Comment: All programs use device drivers: for example, an application which opens a file is using the file system drivers; and applications which use the network are using network drivers.

Comment: @ChrisW: I think he is talking about a program running *its own* device driver, not merely using one.

Answer (score 2):

Is it Windows?

*(Disclaimer: I have no experience with drivers. I'm just finding information from Google)*

- To find out whether a certain piece of code actually runs in ring0, you will need a kernel mode debuger, like WinDbg.
- To find out whether a certain ring3 program communicates with a certain driver, use SysInternals Process Explorer and see if the ring3 program opens any files that says "\Device\something"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvc/thread/5bc594a5-b593-4368-a2b3-31cc5f4a7ddb

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/resources/default.mspx

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/iliast/driver-driver-and-driver-application-communication)

Answer (score 0):

Another sign that a program uses a device driver is that if it imports/invokes the [DeviceIoControl Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx).